# audio-unit sample rate and buffer size

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-audio, audio-recording

i am facing a really misunderstanding when sampling the iphone audio with remoteIO.

from one side, i can do this math: 44khz sample rate means 44 samples per 1ms. which means if i set bufferSize to 0.005 with :

```
float bufferLength = 0.00005;
     AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareIOBufferDuration, sizeof(bufferLength), &bufferLength);
```

which means 5ms buffer size -which means 44*5=220 samples in buffer each callback.
BUT i get 512 samples from `inNumberFrames` each callback . and it stay's fixed even when i change buffer length.

another thing , my callbacks are every 11ms and is not changing! i need faster callbacks .

so !
what is going on here ?
who set what ?

i need to pass a digital information in an FSK modulation, and have to know exactly buffer size in samples, and what time from the signal it has , in order to know how to FFT it  correctly .

any explanation on this ?
thanks a lot.

Comment: `float bufferLength = 0.00005;` would be 50 µs, not 5 ms - this is way too small.

Comment: that was my mistake i have changed it. it sould be 0.005

Comment: It still says 0.00005 in the question - if that's not correct then you need to hit the `edit` button and fix it

Answer (score 5):

There is no way on all current iOS 10 devices to get RemoteIO audio recording buffer callbacks at a faster rate than every 5 to 6 milliseconds.  The OS may even decide to switch to sending even larger buffers at a lower callback rate at runtime.  The rate you request is merely a request, the OS then decides on the actual rates that are possible for the hardware, device driver, and device state.  This rate may or may not stay fixed, so your app will just have to deal with different buffer sizes and rates.

One of your options might be to concatenate each callback buffer onto your own buffer, and chop up this second buffer however you like outside the audio callback.  But this won't reduce actual latency.

Added: some newer iOS devices allow returning audio unit buffers that are shorter than 5.x mS in duration, usually a power of 2 in size at a 48000 sample rate.

Comment: I can get 3ms.  See post above.

Comment: Some newer iOS devices can now do less than 5.3 mS, but not all iOS 10 devices are capable.

Comment: I am trying to get audio samples during 40 ms at 48000 Hz, which turns out to be 1920 samples, but whenever the callback function is called it get 2048 samples and I have measured that the callback function also gets called every 42.6 ms (consistent with 2048 samples at 48000 Hz). Are there just fixed levels of number of samples, and are these always a power of 2 ? Is there any way to control the number of samples that are collected?

Comment: ... I have noticed that no matter what I choose as the duration to collect samples, it automatically chooses something that is a power a 2 and changes the duration accordingly. Is there a way to control this more precisely?

Comment: The buffer size, thus duration is likely based on the iOS devices ADC hardware DMA transfer size, and thus not exposed outside the OS driver to anything like an app API.  So you need to do your own buffering (circular queue/fifo) to get the sizes you need.

Answer (score 3):

> i need to pass a digital information in an FSK modulation, and have to know exactly buffer size in samples, and what time from the signal it has , in order to know how to FFT it correctly.

It doesn't work that way - you don't mandate various hosts or hardware to operate in an exact manner which is optimal for your processing. You can request reduced latency - to a point. Audio systems generally pass streaming pcm data in blocks of samples sized by a power of two for efficient realtime io.

You would create your own buffer for your processor, and report latency (where applicable). You can attempt to reduce wall latency by choosing another sample rate, or by using a smaller N.

Comment: thanks. what is N ? if i decrease sample rate, my callbacks will be faster? i can reduce my sample rate into 10khz.   then my callbacks will be faster? its now 11ms. its slow for me.

Comment: i have decreased the sample rate to 22100 and i sometimes get callbacks each 11ms and sometimes 6ms. its not even closed to fixed. i just need a fixed time callbacks- of about 1ms, and with goertzel algorithm, i am doing the fft, each 1ms again.

Comment: @Rant i was referring to the length of your fft. longer ffts will increase latency (in realtime contexts). re sample rate: maybe, maybe not. it depends on the hardware as well as the software between your program and the hardware. if the buffer size has a minimum, a *higher* sampling rate would produce less latency and your callback frequency would increase. reducing the sample rate could also help, if you are also passed data in smaller chunks. for a program that operates in and is bound by the fft's accuracy, increasing the sample rate would generally just add work for the cpu. (cont)

Comment: (cont) but yes, you could in some circumstances increase the sampling rate and/or reduce the fft length to reduce latency. you'd have to test hardware settings to see which provides the lowest latency (or google) - i don't know the answer to that. once that is established, find an appropriate fft length for your application.

Comment: i think you missed the point. you create your own buffer. report your latency. write to the buffer as samples come in, then read from the buffer of enqueued samples. then produce output -- if you follow, you'll see this process will also introduce latency. your processor cannot rely on a fixed input size. if you open up an AU in logic or garageband, record enable a track, add an insert which uses a long fft, and monitor the effect live, you'll hear the problem there too. no processor can predict the future. processors which need to operate on or analyze periods of time will introduce latency.

Answer (score 1):

The audio session property is a suggested value. You can put in a really tiny number but will just go to the lowest value it can.  The fastest that I have seen on an iOS device when using 16 bit stereo was `0.002902 second` ( ~3ms ).

That is 128 samples (LR stereo frames) per callback.  Thus, 512 bytes per callback.
So `128/44100 = 0.002902 seconds`.

You can check it with:

```
AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareIOBufferDuration, &size, &bufferDuration)
```

Could the value 512 in the original post have meant bytes instead of samples?